# Go XML parsing: set missing attributes to "true"

Tags: xml, go

The snippet below,

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var r struct {
        Item []struct {
            Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
            Flag bool `xml:"flag,attr"`
        } `xml:"item"`
    }
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(`
        <result>
            <item value="1" flag="false" />
            <item value="2" flag="true" />
            <item value="3" />
        </result>`,
    ), &r)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r)
}
```

Will print the following result:

```
{Item:[{Value:1 Flag:false} {Value:2 Flag:true} {Value:3 Flag:false}]}
```

In some elements, `flag` attribute will be missing (e.g. item 3 above), but I want it to take the default value of `true`, instead than `false`.

1. I cannot assign it in the constructor, because I don't know the number of elements in the array upfront.
2. I cannot use a custom type that implements `UnmarshalerAttr` and assign during unmarshaling because if the attribute is missing, `UnmarshalXMLAttr` is not run.
3. I could make it a pointer, and then check if nil, then true, but that's just gross and error-prone.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct in that you cannot use `UnmarshalerAttr` for this. Instead, `ResultItem` can implement [`Unmarshaler`](https://godoc.org/encoding/xml#Unmarshaler) which will allow you to set default attribute values:

```
package main
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type ResultItem struct {
  Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
  Flag bool `xml:"flag,attr"`
}

func (ri *ResultItem) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
  type resultItem ResultItem // new type to prevent recursion
  item := resultItem{
    Flag: true,
  }
  if err := d.DecodeElement(&item, &start); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  *ri = (ResultItem)(item)
  return nil
}

func main() {
    var r struct {
      Item[] ResultItem `xml:"item"`
    }
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(`
        <result x="ASDASD">
            <item value="1" flag="false" />
            <item value="2" flag="true" />
            <item value="3" />
        </result>`,
    ), &r)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r)
}
```

Comment: One addition: instead of re-defining an anonymous struct, create a `type ResultItem resultItem` and use that in the function, will do just as well without duplicating struct definition.

Comment: seems a bit magical to need to use that local type, is this considered idiomatic? I would've never figured this out myself